# Raid5 with 3 / 2TB drives shows only 2TB capacity buy fdisk reports 4

Tags: debian-squeeze

Debian Squeeze 64 Dell R510.

Can someone explain why df -h shows my raid 5 sata with 3 / 2TB drives shows up as 2.0T capacity but when I do fdisk -l it shows something different

```
me@scf:/mnt/raid5$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             225G  4.8G  209G   3% /
tmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  7.9G  148K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1             2.0T  1.5T  479G  76% /mnt/raid5
```

and fdisk -f

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3999.7 GB, 3999688294400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486267 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4d9f5ba6

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1 1      267349  2147480811   83  Linux
```

Raid Controller

```
02:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic LSI MegaSAS 9260 (rev 05)
```

Is this something I need to worry about?  Not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've probably stumbled into a 32-bit/64-bit problem. Disks with the MBR partitioning layout are limited to a 2TB maximum drive size due to the field widths in the partition table and the block-size; the field is 32-bits wide, but with a 512 block-size 2TB is as big as it allows. You can get higher with 4K-block devices, but those don't appear to be used in your system.

GPT partitioning does allow larger disk sizes, but you need to use `parted` not `fdisk` to create that kind of layout.

Comment: Bringing myself up to seed on this right now.  Thanks for the your answer.